# no setter/getter found in class android error

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my android code.

```
No setter/field for richest-man-in-babylon found on class com.test.test.Book
```

Here is the code that retrieves information about books from firebase

```
  var list = ArrayList<Book> ()
    val bookListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            for (eventSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Book::class.java)!!);
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w("Book", "loadBook:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
            // ...
        }
    }
    database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(bookListener)
```

then it loads the information into this Book class

```
class Book {
    var title : String = ""
    var subtitle : String = ""
    var uploadDate : Int = 0
    var image : String = ""

        get() = field       // field here ~ `this.firstName` in Java or normally `_firstName` is C#
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }

    constructor () {

    }
    constructor (title : String, subtitle: String, image: String, uploadDate: Int) {
        this.title = title;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
        this.image = image;
        this.uploadDate = uploadDate;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add each book's title and subtitle to the Book object.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Here's the structure for the firebase table

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact contents of the document you're trying to map into a Book object.

Comment: See question. Thanks!

Comment: K I added it. It's under "books"

Comment: I don't understand - you're trying to put that entire books note into a Book object?  Or are you actually working with one of those many child nodes?  Please be specific.

Comment: I'm trying to put that entire books into the book object. Only some fields of the each book - only the title, subtitle.

Comment: You cannot map the entire `books` node into a `Book` object. Perhaps you should consider mapping each child into a `Book` object. It will be more appropriate.